# Mac tools for control multiple monitors?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

Are there any Mac apps that will enhance my multiple monitor experience? Something like [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) for the Mac?

I'd like to extend the application bar and dock across both monitors, and easily transfer windows from one screen to the other.

Comment: Is this question targeted exclusively at Mac users who also have Windows and use Ultramon?  If not, then why not explain what functionality you want?

Answer (score 2):

[SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) and [MercuryMover](http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover) allow you to move and resize windows using the keyboard.

[SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) is focused on *tiling* windows.  There are shortcuts for resizing windows to the various half- and quarter- screen sizes and positions.  It also shortcuts to move windows to the "next" and "previous" displays.

[MercuryMover](http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover) is extremely flexible, it's intended to allow you to do all sorts of moving and resizing using the keyboard.  It has presets, like SizeUp, but they user-configurable -- and there is a heads up display for letting you do custom actions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything like Ultramon for the Mac.  However, here are two products I've used on Mac OS X to improve my multiple monitor setup:

[ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com) lets you use an old Windows laptop as an external monitor for OS X.  It works using VNC so it's a little slow.

[Gefen USB DVI Adapter](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=4517) lets you connect a 2nd display to a Mac via USB.  I use it with a MacBook Pro so that I have 2 external displays in addition to the MacBook's display.  It works great.

I haven't tried this, but it was just announced this week: [OWC USB to DVI adapter](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/VIDU2DVIA/).

Answer (score 1):

[SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) adds shortcuts for moving windows between monitors.

Answer (score 1):

[Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com) works great for resizing windows in MacOS. It's free and shorcuts are customizable.

Answer (score 0):

If they're on different physical computers, I'd make use of [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/), which is a cross-platform KVM solution. (without the "V")

Comment: Nah, man, this is one Mac with 2 monitors

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) as others have mentioned to move windows between monitors.

As far as the "application bar" I assume you mean the menu bar. While you can't get a menu bar on both monitors the application [DejaMenu](http://homepage.mac.com/khsu/DejaMenu/DejaMenu.html) will pop up a menu bar as a contextual menu with a keyboard shortcut that you assign to it. You could also trigger DejaMenu by clicking or hovering in a screen corner with [CornerClick](http://greg.vario.us/cornerclick/) or via a right click with [FinderPop](http://www.finderpop.com/). To use CornerClick or FinderPop you will want [this](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080415061724969) little app to trigger DejaMenu.

SizeUp is $13, and all others I've mentioned are free / donationware.

There are quite a few applications to modify the dock, but none that I know of that let you have two docks. Take a look at [macupdate.com](http://search.macupdate.com/search.php?keywords=dock&os=mac) and perhaps you'll find something.